# Uncaught ReferenceError In Knockout Js

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

I have my own knockout's component:

```
ko.components.register("library-link-form",
{
  viewmodel: LibraryLinkViewModel,
  template: { controller: "PartialViews", action: "LibraryLinkPartial" } 
  //This is custom template loader, which loads asp.net partial view from controller via ajax request.
});
```

My `LibraryLinkViewModel.js`:

```
function LibraryLinkViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.OtherLibrary = ko.observable("");

  self.Type = ko.observable("");  
}
```

Partial view `_LibraryLinkForm`:

```
@{
    var libraryDropdownId = $"dropdown-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8)}";
    var typeDropdownId = $"dropdown-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8)}";
    var scriptId = $"script-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8)}";
    var contextId = $"context-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8)}";
    var librariesList = //some list with predefined libraries
    var typeList = // some list with predefined library's types
}
<!-- ko template: { afterRender: function()
{
eval($('#@scriptId').html());
}
}
-->
<!-- /ko -->
<div id ="@contextId">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                      .Name(libraryDropdownId)
                      .DataValueField("Value").DataTextField("Text")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new
                      {
                        style = "width: 100%",
                        data_bind = "value: OtherLibrary"
                      }).BindTo(librariesList).Deferred()
                    )
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                        .Name(typeDropdownId)
                        .DataValueField("Value").DataTextField("Text")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new
                        {
                          style = "width: 100%",
                          data_bind = "value: Type"
                        }).BindTo(typeList).Deferred()
                        )
                  </div>                     
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <deferred-script class="hidden" id="@scriptId">
    @(Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts(false))
  </deferred-script>
</div>
```

And finally, how I combine it all:

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: addLibraryLink"></button>
<ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: LibraryLinks">
    <li><library-link-form></library-link-form></li>    
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LibraryViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.LibraryLinks = ko.observableArray();
        self.addLibraryLink = function () {
            ko.components.clearCachedDefinition();
            self.LibraryLinks.push(new LibraryLinkViewModel());
       };
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new LibraryViewModel());
</script>
```

I'm using Knockout v.3.4, Asp.Net Core v.1.0.0.

So, the problem is that when I'm trying to add new library link to list, knockout bindings simply don't work, maybe because of error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function
>   (){return OtherLibrary }" Message: OtherLibrary is not defined

What should I do with this error? How can I properly add my knockout's component to the list?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and seeing what the KO context is at that point? It could be that the HTML is not referencing `LibraryLinkViewModel` there or something. I really cant' tell if that would be the case or not from here as I've not really done that much C#. It just seems like incorrect context is the most likely. thing there.

Comment: Yes, I've tried debugging, especially with `ko.toJSON($data)` in `_LibraryLinkForm`, it shows nothing! Seems that something wrong with adding items to ul, because of losing context in child items. But I can't understand where context lost, or whatever it done.

Comment: Install [this addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en) (it's Chrome only) and then use the debug tools. Do not go to the KnockoutJS tab (it's useless), instead select the HTML element you want and then go to **Knockout context** on the right panel: [here is an example](http://i.imgur.com/fWHbUAG.png). The plugin is _extremely_ useful in these sorts of situations - you can start walking up the parents in the HTML and see where or if the context changes. You need to remove the error first - just set the binding to a string

Comment: I've already installed this addon, checked, and it proved that context lost in `_LibraryLinkForm`. Anyway, can you say, that this way of manipulating with array is correct? Also, what do you mean by _You need to remove the error first - just set the binding to a string_?

Comment: Set the data-bind to `value: "string"` - this will the ReferenceError as it won't be trying to reference the property. This might change what you see in the Knockout context. As for the manipulation being correct - it _might_ be. You might need to make sure you switch the context which can be done using the `foreach: items` in KO which will make everything underneath be in the context of the element in the array, so you will be able to access their properties. Again, I'm not sure what the C# is doing but I would hope it's doing that.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I already have `data-bind="foreach: LibraryLinks"` isn't that enough for switching context? Anyway, I'll try it tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. Let's look at the example, and check contexts in it:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: LibraryLinks"> // here we have LibraryViewModel context
    <library-link-form> // here we have LibraryLinkViewModel context
        //inside component we have THIRD context, which is empty!
    </library-link-form>  
</div>
```

So, the problem is, that *OtherLibrary* in `data_bind = "value: OtherLibrary"` refers to the third context, which is empty and nowhere defined.

Simply calling parent's context solves the problem.

For example: `data_bind = "value: $parent.OtherLibrary"`